# Declined flag: Is this a subtle put-down?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags, code-of-conduct

I recently had an "Unfriendly or unkind" comment flag declined on a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62618838/208273) that was something to the effect of:

> Start with using a spell-checker.

This appears to be a sarcastic shot at the asker for misspelling "Transaction" as "Transection" (the only misspelling in the post, though it was made twice). That seems like the sort of "subtle put-down" referenced in the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)—a subtler version of the "Are you speaking English? If so, I can’t tell." given as an example there.

That was the only word misspelled, so I can't imagine this was even an attempt at suggesting that the question would have been at all clearer had their spelling been better (indeed, the spelling was not remotely the problem with that post).  The comment was removed, assumedly for being no longer necessary.

If this isn't a subtle put-down, where should we draw that line when flagging comments?

Comment: I hardly think this is worth litigating. I interpreted the comment a bit differently until I clicked through to the post. At that point, it was obviously unnecessary and perhaps borderline insulting, so I deleted it.

Comment: @CodyGray I mostly wanted to make sure I was understanding the code of conduct properly.  I think your comment answers that to my satisfaction—thanks.

Comment: When it's even a little bit subjective or subject to interpretation, prefer "no longer needed" flags on comments.

Comment: @JeanneDark there's technically no consequences for any comment flags. The only thing a sufficient amount of flags does is raise an automatic mod flag. Flags are used to provide context to a moderation decision rather than triggering anything automatic. It's not like spam or R/A flags on posts where you get -100 rep for 6 flags (or up to 5 + 1 from a mod)

Comment: My classification would be closer to "non constructive" than offensive. On the one hand, it is a comment that shouldn't have been posted in the first place (they could have edited the question to fix those mistakes). On the other hand, if we assume good faith, all we see is a suggestion to spell-check the post.

Comment: @E_net4wasonaboat: the old "if you can't be bothered to put some effort into asking your question, why then expect an effort from us answering it?" But posting that *verbatim* will result in a stern e-mail from a moderator, so let's be nice and tiptoe around it. Or, silently downvote because of low quality.

Comment: If the problem that the question was asking about was directly related to the misspelling of the word, it could be a useful comment (though it would be *better* if it was worded differently and more clearly). If the word's spelling has no impact on what the question is asking, then the comment is just noise and should go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give that one an answer, citing from the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399634/declined-flag-is-this-a-subtle-put-down#comment784091_399634) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399634/declined-flag-is-this-a-subtle-put-down#comment784093_399634) a moderator who reviewed that comment again.

"...it was obviously unnecessary and perhaps borderline insulting, so I deleted it."

So the flag was kind of helpful. The advice is to use "no longer needed" flags on comments if it is "even a little bit subjective or subject to interpretation".